# Mapping folder in docker compose on Windows

Tags: windows, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a working Windows container, binding works using `docker run`. But I need to make it work inside docker-compose file. Last error I got is *invalid bind mount source, must be an absolute path*

My swarm runs Docker 18.09.5, 3 linux managers and 3 Windows 2019 workers.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: 192.168.1.1:5000/sample
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: logs
        target: C:\Logs

volumes:
  logs:
    driver: host
    driver_opts:
      source: C:\Docker\Logs\
```

I came to a property `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` but haven't found any docs about it, so don't know how to set up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is quite old and described in this [moby issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34810).

Linux manager prepends current path before Windows path resulting in non-sense. I had to promote one Windows worker to manager and run the `docker stack deploy` from there.